# Capturing video stream to <canvas> on iOS

Tags: html, ipad, html5-canvas, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to capture Ipad's video output into a browser using html5 tag(may be canvas or some other)..
How is that possible??
Also i assume that iPad streams video as component output format.

Answer (score 0):

There exist an API called [getUserMedia()](http://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia) to open streams of webcams, microphone, screencast and such fort streaming.

However Apple does not provide this API for iOS yet, so you basically cannot do it with web app. I am not sure if ti is even possible with a native app.